# Cron job in CodeIgniter doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I set up my cron job like this. Here is my command

```
php public_html/project_name/index.php cron cronExec
```

*cronExec* is a function in my controller name cron. That will save a data into my database.

Anyways, does index.php really need to put in command? I set my config.php into this code:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

It should execute every minute I already set it in my cron job but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux server, try below method

In cli type following,

```
crontab -e
```

It will open corntab configuration file in a editor, Then insert following line and save it.

```
*/60 * * * * wget -O /dev/null http://YourLocalhost/PathToYourFunction
```

This URL will execute by your server every 1 minute interval.

Answer (score 0):

You need set full absolute path to `index.php`.